# background-color property not taking up entire li

Tags: html, navigationbar

I have this HTML5 code:

```
<div id = 'nav'>
    <ul>
        <a href = ''>
            <li>HOME</li>
        </a>
        <a href = ''>
            <li class = 'final_nav'>FAQ</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this CSS stylesheet:

```
#nav {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 22px;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
.final_nav {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But when I hover over a `nav li`, the `the background-color: #A9A9A9` property doesn't work as I would like it to:
[image]

How do I alter the CSS so that the dark-grey background will take up the whole `li` but not the borders?
Thanks

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I realised this code works perfectly when alone, but when I include the parent div, the code then produces the error above. Here is the whole header code:

HTML:

```
<div id = 'header'>
    <h1>CONTEST CODING</h1>
    <p>The free programming competition for everyone</p>
    <div id = 'nav'>
        <ul>
            <a href = ''>
                <li>HOME</li>
            </a>
            <a href = ''>
                <li class = 'final_nav'>FAQ</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#nav {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 22px;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
.final_nav {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can anyone now help me with my `background-color` problem?

Comment: You have invalid HTML. The `<a>` should be inside the `<li>`

Comment: I see you edited the question with new code, but you still did not fix the invalid HTML. Notice in my, or DJDavid98's, answer that we've placed the `<a>` inside the `<li>`. You should not wrap `<li>` with anything but an `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, wrapping `<li>` elements in ancor tags is not the best way to do this. It's the other way around. If you switch it over, then all your CSS works fine.

```
<div id = 'nav'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href = ''>HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="final_nav">
            <a href = ''>FAQ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/xZQ6E/)

Comment: interesting. just putting line breaks in the `<li>` before and after the `<a>` does the trick. good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `display: inline;` on the `<li>` items, the spaces between them (or line breaks) in the HTML are getting rendered as if it was all text.

If you change your HTML to have no spaces between the `<li>` and also put the `<a>` inside the `<li>`, the background color should fill each item when hovered.

```
<div id = 'nav'>
    <ul>

            <li><a href = ''>HOME</a></li><li class = 'final_nav'><a href = ''>FAQ</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fvIiL)